# It was vs it would have been in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, difference

It was vs it would have been in the context

Hello teachers! which one is correct here using "was" or " would have been", and how do they differ in the meaning if both are correct?

For example:

It was/ would have been fun of the heart attachment if the fire of love had started equally, neither you nor I would have found repose

Comment: Sorry, that phrase is hard to understand. Did you mean *if* instead of *of*? What is this sentence supposed to express? Please [edit] some context into your question.

Answer (score 2):

"Would have been" is normally counterfactual, describing something that didn't happen, for an explicit or implicit reason.
"Was" is past tense

- It **was** nice to see you yesterday, I'm glad I went
- It **would have been** nice to see you yesterday, I'm sorry I didn't go

It's not quite clear what your example sentence is supposed to mean, but "*if* the fire of love *had* started equally" and "*would have* found" implies it is counterfactual: so you need "would have been".

I'm not sure what "fun of the heart attachment" is intended to mean, perhaps "the joy of the romantic attachment" or "the joy of the affair of the heart":

Perhaps:

> It would have been a joyous affair of the heart if the fire of love had started equally

But "neither you nor I would have found repose" seems a contradiction: unequal love doesn't normally make calm!

Comment: Thanks, but I asked the difference in my context

Comment: It's the same meaning.  Also: are you sure your context sentence is correct "It was fun of the heart attachment ..." isn't grammatical.

Comment: What's the reason it's ungrammatical? On what basis do you say so? Is it grammatical " I am sorry if I have offended you"?

Comment: No my friend, certainly not offended!  I expanded my answer, hope it's helpful.

Comment: I mean "neither you nor I would have found repose" was fun of the heart's attachment if the fire of love had started equally  :)