# Was with Would have been

Tags: grammar

Can we use `was`with `would have been`?. I would like understand how do we say if the two hypothetical situations occur in the past.

Example :

1. If lockdown was not imposed, condition would have been serious
2. If lockdown had not been imposed, condition would have been serious

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. The Simple Past (version #1) implies *the speaker doesn't know* whether the ***if-*** condition is True or False, where Past Perfect (version #2) explicitly indicates that the specified condition is "unreal, hypothetical" (it ***didn't*** happen - except in this *specific* case that condition itself is negated, so the "net" condition is that lockdown ***was*** imposed). Note that idiomatically, it's plural ***conditions*** in this context, not singular ***condition***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It was vs it would have been in the context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/207878/it-was-vs-it-would-have-been-in-the-context)

Comment: Can you elaborate your first comment to make it as an answer?. It is bit clumsy now.